# Python Wand text - "€"Symbol

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand, drawtext

I'm looking for a way to display the Euro symbol (€) in a text drawing. It's currently been displayed as shown below:

[image: Result]

Code:

```
from wand.drawing import Drawing as WandDrawing
from wand.image import Image as WandImage

    with WandDrawing() as draw:
        with WandImage(filename="image.jpg") as img:
            text = "Price: €3,200.00"
            draw.font = "font.otf"
            draw.fill_color = WandColor("Turquoise")
            draw.font_size = 10
            draw.text_alignment = "center"
            draw.text(50, 10, text)
            
            draw(img)
```

Desired result

Price: €3,200.00

The [documentation](https://imagemagick.org/api/drawing-wand.php#DrawSetTextEncoding) states that UTF-8 encoding is being used, so I don't understand why this symbol isn't being displayed why others similar ($, &..) are.

**Solved**

View comments for answer

Comment: did you try this one ? iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-15 ? Please let me know

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Wuzardor iso-8859-1 does not include '€', while iso-8859-15 does. Unfortunately, I did not find any reference on how to specify the ISO version for that Draw object

Comment: @PedroMaia Improved the question, thanks for the tip

Comment: How do you specify the encoding of your source code? If it is not specified in the clear in the python source with a line such as `# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-` or similar all bets are off.

Comment: @xenoid solved, thanks anyway!

Comment: Better make a separate answer and mark your questions accepted

Answer (score 0):

The error originated while reading the content of an external file that was used as the text for the image, which contained the "€" symbol. I know this was not reflected in my above code, I erroneously excluded it.

```
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    return file.read()
```

Adding `encoding='utf-8'` solved the issue.
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkjIC.jpg)